# HTML5 audio tag not working on react-native-webview on android but works on IOS

Tags: android, html, react-native, audio, react-native-webview

I have a react-native application where i load this page (https://vibrez-rugby.com/perpignan-en-direct/) in a webview using [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview)
I use react-native-webview 10.3.2 and android 7.0 to test

Everything works fine on ios but on android, the audio tag is disabled.

[click to see audio tag on android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUS3l.png)

I can't find the problem, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I was having the same problem and found an solution for it, just wanted to share what worked for me

The audio src must be an **https** url, ios was accepting http ones but for android it has to be a secure address, or it won't load the file